# FactoryGirl ID association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, factory-bot

Hello, I'm trying to do test but I have some problems. First, file `conn.rb`:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :conn, class: Connection do
    from_id         1
    to_id       4
    end
end
```

Second file, `leg.rb`:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
factory :leg_le, class: Leg do
    association :connection_id, factory: :conn
    from_id         1
    to_id           2
end
end
```

And my goal is to create `leg_le` with `ID` of `conn`:

```
 conn=FactoryGirl.create(:conn)
 leg=FactoryGirl.create(:leg_le)
```

It seems to create but `connection_id` is `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try :

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :connection do
        from_id    1
        to_id      4
    end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :leg do
        association :connection, factory: :connection
        from_id         1
        to_id           2
    end
end
```

then

```
FactoryGirl.create(:leg).connection_id
    # => 1 or whatever your connection_id is
```

or (if you want to reuse the connection instance elsewhere) :

```
connection = FactoryGirl.create(:connection)
FactoryGirl.create(:leg, :connection=> connection).connection_id
    # => 1 or whatever your connection_id is
```